# Reducing Exchange Mailbox Sizes to Less Than Their Current Size?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, powershell, exchange-2010, mailbox

What will happen if I set all mailbox size limits back to exchange defaults on a network if a user's mailbox is greater than the default amount.

I don't personally want to try this, but do I have to get everyone under the new default size before I can use powershell to set everyone back to defaults.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean "set the sizes"? You can lower the size limits, and what happens is people can't send/receive email anymore (depending which limit you change), but the sizes won't change. If you want to shrink them, you need to delete content from them.

Comment: Sorry, I mean mailbox size limit for users on the network

Comment: oh ok so if they are over the limit they just can't send/receive email?

Comment: @MikeKellogg - Yes